# Is there a way to save an html page using Nodejs, angular or just javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, node.js

Let's say i make a website and i would like to save one of it's webpages locally as an .html file. I was wondering if there was a way to do this. I don't think its possible with just javascript and im still new to angular and node. I want it to work similarly to the way chrome does it ( right click--> save as). I was gonna create a button on the webpage that would allow the user to save the html locally if they wanted it. Thanks

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. What have you tried? Should this work in browser? From a server? ... Whatever the case is you will have to be more specific.

Comment: i mean... you could package it up server-side ahead of time and have a route in node.js that serves it....

Comment: I was hoping to create a function that i would call onclick with a button that would save the html page to the users disk

Comment: It sounds like you should just use what you already alluded to. *( right click--> save as)* Unless you have a more specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the source code whenever you want using some javascript

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;
```

You will have to write a small script to match all the external resources urls.

Bassicaly these are : css, js, images, links

If you want to save these files on your hard drive, you can't because javascript doesn't have the right to write on your disk.

It's not maybe what you want but to get a nice PDF of the page, you can use PhantomJS.

Comment: @TaimoorKhan theoretically. but it's unlikely that it would run properly for the user.

Comment: @Taimoor angular need to be run client side, have a look at phantomjs, it's a command line browser so it trigger javascript. I used it for PDF generation, it can probably do more.

Comment: I'll check out phantomjs and make it a pdf. I think that's probably the best way to do this. Ill post my code up when i've got it running. Thanks guys

Comment: Ok there are plenty of example. Keep in mind that the documentation and article you can find online is not always up to date since phantomJS changed a lot these last years but it's a good solution I used in production for more than a year now. If you liked my answer feel free to accept it.